# Is there a way to have a shutdown hook for a Github CodeSpace?

Tags: github-actions, vscode-devcontainer, codespaces, github-codespaces

We have a `devcontainer.json` that provides us with the environment that we need in order to run CodeSpaces and build our project. This involves starting a bash script that creates a [Postgres.ai](https://postgres.ai/) snapshot for the developer to have up and running.

Is there a way we can have a "shutdown hook" that is called before the CodeSpace is deleted? Not sure if what I'm asking is supposed to be inside the `devcontainer.json` or a Github Workflow event that triggers a workflow upon CodeSpace deletion. The idea is to be able to clean-up the Postgres.AI snapshot dedicated to the CodeSpace that would obviously be no longer needed.

The [devcontainer.json schema](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_schema/) mentioned only a `shutdownAction` but that seems to be something else?